# exception "nullable value must have a value" for datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to assign 'null' value to `Datetime?` object. But it is throwing `"nullable value must have a value"` exception.

```
 //item.PlannedStartDate value is nothing.
 fact_Initiative.Start_Date = If([String].IsNullOrEmpty(item.PlannedStartDate), 
    DBNull.Value, CType(Convert.ToDateTime(item.PlannedStartDate), 
    System.Nullable(Of Date)))
```

How to solve this

Comment: are you sure that fact_Initiative.Start_Date has a type of Nullable<DateTime>?

Comment: Also, I doubt `DBNull.Value` will work here. Can you show some of the surrounding code for context? I have the feeling there's a nice solution waiting if we just had a bit more to go on.

Comment: @AlexeyRaga it is `DateTime?`

Answer (score 1):

```
fact_Initiative.Start_Date =If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.PlannedStartDate), CType(Nothing, DateTime?), DateTime.Parse(item.PlannedStartDate))
```